# in jQuery how to give the priority of being detected by "mouseover" event to the child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

my question is how to give the priority of being detected by "mouseover" event to the child element rather than its parent?

**this is the jquery code:**

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("li").mouseover(function(event){
        $('#log').html($(this).text());
    });
}); 
</script>
```

**and this is the html code**

```
  <ul>
     <li>item 1</li>
     <li>item 2</li>
     <li>item 3
        <ul>
           <li>item 3.1</li>
           <li>item 3.2</li>
           <li>item 3.3</li>
        </ul>
     </li>
     <li>item 4</li>
  </ul>

  <div id="log">log</div>
```

how to output the current element when doing mouseover?

the problem is when you mouseover "item 3.1"  the jquery will not detect "item 3.1" and instead jquery will assume that you mouseover "item 3" ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You want the [event target](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#target):

```
$("li").mouseover(function(event) {
    $('#log').html($(event.target).text());
});
```

From quirksmode (linked above):

> Even if an event is captured or
>   bubbles up, the target/srcElement
>   always remains the element the event
>   took place on.

[**Demo here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/mzQGT/)

Answer (score 1):

Add a `span` inside each `li` around the text, and check for a mouse over on that

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("li span").mouseover(function(event){
        $('#log').html($(this).text());
    });
}); 
</script>   

<ul>
    <li><span>item 1</span></li>
    <li><span>item 2</span></li>
    <li><span>item 3</span>
        <ul>
           <li><span>item 3.1</span></li>
           <li><span>item 3.2</span></li>
           <li><span>item 3.3</span></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><span>item 4</span></li>
</ul>

<div id="log">log</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should select the inner 'li' tags instead of all 'li' tags.

For example, you could add a `class='innerItem"` to inner 'li', like this:

```
<li class='innerItem'>item 3.1</li>
```

Then your jQuery should look like this:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("li.innerItem").mouseover(function(event){
        $('#log').html($(this).text());
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think the requestor wants to see the text of only the nested items, but of whatever LI he happens to be hovering over.

Comment: Thanks, I want to detect all li elements even parents and grandchildren, so this will not solve my case, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative to Karim79 method.

```
$("li").mouseover(function(event){
    $('#log').html($(this).text());
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Make sure to read what [stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) actually does.

http://jsbin.com/afunu3